# What is the maximum length of command line arguments in gnome-terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

What is the maximum length of command line arguments in gnome-terminal?

... and is there a system environment variable which reports this value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846263/maximum-length-of-command-line-argument-that-can-be-passed-to-sqlplus-from-lin || http://askubuntu.com/questions/14081/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-command-line-arguments-in-gnome-terminal || http://serverfault.com/questions/163371/linux-command-line-character-limit || http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`xargs` knows. On my system,

```
$ xargs --show-limits
Your environment variables take up 2572 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2092532
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2089960
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
```

Comment: To expand on this, the limit is not in the terminal, it's in the kernel (and in the shell, as well, but I think the default shell (bash)'s limit is as high as the kernel limit). Also, `xargs` isn't just for reporting the limit, it's also (primarily) for working around it — see the man page or other documentation.

Comment: I like this answer, particularly because of the "could actually use" output... I've twiddled with it a bit and came up with this command variant to isolate the "actually" value... (maybe there's a simpler way, but hey, it works and is suitable for a script: `xargs --show-limits --no-run-if-empty < /dev/null 2>&1 |sed -n "/could actually use/s/.*: \\([0-9]\+\\)/\1/p"`

Comment: Strangely, xargs seems to double-count the environment limit in the POSIX limit (POSIX limit = ARG_MAX - 2048 (headroom) - envvars).

Answer (score 18):

The answer comes from the *sysconf* value `ARG_MAX`. To examine it on your system:

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

For me, this reports `2097152`. For more details check the manpage:

```
man sysconf
```

To get this inside a program, for example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
...
printf("%ld\n", sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX));
```

Comment: Thanks KC.. +1; a neat way to get the absolute MAX, but I've preferred the xargs method because of its "actually available" factor... as I was actually after a run-time value (but I didn't mention that :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about gnome-terminal, but the shell has not a 'fixed' limit, but the limit of the stack.

However there is an hardcode limit per-argument that is 128KB, that should not be a problem if you don't use 'very very very long arguments....'.

You can read more about this here:

http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-make@gnu.org/msg05522.html