# Argument list too long error

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a command that only contains 4 arguments, one of which has a value of ~150,000 characters. When I run the command, I receive an error stating `Argument list too long`.

I searched for a solution to similar problems, and someone recommended `xargs`. I don't think this is is applicable to my problem, as I'm trying to pass a *single argument that is 150k+ characters*.

Here's a shortened version of what I'm trying to run:

`appname -arg foo -arg2 bar -arg {150k characters}`

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the data via a filename instead of via the actual data?

Comment: You mean something like this? `appname -arg foo -arg2 bar -arg file.txt`

Comment: Yes. If there is, there's a nice way to do it without an actual file.

Comment: How does this circumvent my original problem of having too many characters in my command?

Comment: If the program allows you to pass all those characters in via a file, the program will get the characters it needs.

Comment: You could be up against a hard limit.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/14081/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-command-line-arguments-in-gnome-terminal