# find a file with "find" and show the size of the file

Tags: command-line, files, find

How can I find a file at the same time view the size of the file? 
ERROR: I tried this command, but I only got the size and details of other files.

```
find -name "*.conf" | ls -l
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`find` has a `-ls` option. So your command should look like this:

```
find -name '*.conf' -ls
```

Answer (score 8):

An option is specify your own format with `-printf`.  For example this will output the filesize followed by a space then the filename (with relative path):

```
find -name "*.conf" -printf "%s %p\n"
```

You can end your format string with `\0` instead of `\n` if you want to NUL-separate find's output records, in the case you expect funny filenames (e.g. those including newlines).

---

For the record, the attempt shown in your question doesn't work because you are trying to pipe output from `find` to input to `ls`.  `ls` does not read any input from STDIN, so the output from `find` is simply discarded and then `ls` lists the content of the current directory, as usual.

Answer (score 6):

Other answers already have pointed out

1. [how to print the filesize with `find` only, using `-printf`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038796/507051)
2. [how to get an `ls` output with `find` only, using `-ls`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038765/507051)
3. [how to properly pipe `find`'s output to another program with `xargs`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038861/507051)

However, the first and second approach don’t give the exact output of `ls -l` (the `-ls` flag equals `ls -dils`) and the third one needs an additional `xargs` call. With the help of the `-exec` flag it’s possible to call `ls -l` directly from `find`:

```bsh
find -name "*.conf" -exec ls -l {} +
```

This gives the whole list of file names as arguments to `ls -l` and calls it as just as many times as necessary.

---

If you just want to match every file ending in `.conf` in and under the current directory (and [`ARG_MAX`](https://askubuntu.com/q/14081/507051) isn’t a problem!),  **you actually don’t need `find` at all**. Instead you can use `bash`’s glob matching with the `globstar` and `dotglob` shell options as follows –  it’s equally wise enough not to break on newlines in file names and matches “hidden” files like `find`:

```bsh
$ shopt -s globstar dotglob
$ ls -l **/*.conf
```

Answer (score 4):

`ls` doesn't get its list of files from standard input, it expects them to be arguments. The `xargs` command is a general facility for turning input into arguments:

```
find -name '*.conf' | xargs ls -l
```

However, this will split the input at whitespace, so you can have problems if any of the names have spaces. `find` and `xargs` have options that work together to mitigate this:

```
find -name '*.conf' -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l
```

The `-0` option to `xargs` tells it to use a null byte as the delimiter between parameters in the input, and `-print0` tells `find` to print the names separated by a null byte instead of newline.