# Create directories with a name from txt file which contain '/' character

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, text-processing

I have a .txt file that contains a text like this

```
A1/B1/C1
A2/B2/C2 
A3/B3/C3
```

I want a script that reads the .txt file for each line then create a directory based on the first word (A1, A2, A3)

I have created script like this:

```
file="test.txt"
while IFS='' read -r line
do
    name="line"
    mkdir -p $line
done <"$file"
```

While I run it, it creates directory A1 then it also create sub-directories B1 and C1. the same happens for another line (A2* and A3*)

What should I do to create only A1, A2, A3 directories?

I don't want to make the name like A1/B1/C1 with '/' character in it. 
I just want to take the word before '/' character and make it directory name. 
Just "A1" "A2" "A3".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just `cut` the `1`st slash-`d`elimited field of each line and give the list to `mkdir`:

```bsh
mkdir $(<dirlist.txt cut -d/ -f1)
```

#### Example run

```bsh
$ cat dirlist.txt 
A1/A2/A3
B1/B2/B3
C1/C2/C3
$ ls
dirlist.txt
$ mkdir $(<dirlist.txt cut -d/ -f1)
$ ls
A1  B1  C1  dirlist.txt
```

You may run into [ARG_MAX](https://askubuntu.com/q/14081/507051) problems if your list holds a *huge* number of directory names, in this case use GNU `parallel` [image: Install parallel] or `xargs` as follows:

```bsh
parallel mkdir :::: <(<dirlist.txt cut -d/ -f1)
xargs -a<(<dirlist.txt cut -d/ -f1) mkdir
```

While `parallel` has it covered, the `xargs` approach won’t work if the directory names contain spaces – you can either use `\0` as the line delimiter or simply instruct `xargs` to only split the input on newline characters (as proposed by [Martin Bonner](https://askubuntu.com/users/570297/martin-bonner)) instead:

```bsh
xargs -0a<(<dirlist.txt tr \\{n,0} | cut -d/ -f1 -z) mkdir # \\{n,0} equals \\n \\0
xargs -d\\n -a<(<dirlist.txt cut -d/ -f1) mkdir
```

In case any of the fields contains a newline character one would need to identify the “true” line endings and replace only those newline characters with e.g. `\0`. That would be a case for `awk`, but I feel it’s too far fetched here.

Comment: Why `xargs -a<(....)` rather than `<dirlist.txt cut -d/ -f1 | xargs`?

Comment: @MartinBonner Thanks for clarifying, that’s indeed simpler than my `tr` approach – just realized that `parallel` has it covered by default.

Comment: @MartinBonner *Why `xargs -a<(....)` rather than a pipe* – because I like it this way, as simple as that. :)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Oh, now I understand. `<(...)` helps with spaces as well, so it’s definitely the better choice – I don’t think anybody was using this file descriptor anyway.

Comment: @MartinBonner More interestingly: [Why `cut <dirlist.txt` instead of just `cut dirlist.txt`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70759/246819)

Comment: Did you intentionally obfuscate `tr "\n" "\0"` to that `tr \\{n,0}`?

Comment: @ilkkachu How is that obfuscating? I think it’s actually more clear, it shows the two comma-separated next to each other – brace expansion is quite common and easy to understand, isn’t this even a C shell feature?

Comment: @dessert, sure, and `tr "\n" "\0"` or `tr \\n \\0` shows two arguments next to each other, space separated. In exactly the usual way to write command line arguments. Brace expansion may be common, yes, but it still brings up questions from time to time so it's not like it's immediately obvious to everyone in every case. And it only saves one character here. In the same vein, you could have written `cut -{d/,f1,z}`. It would also show the flags comma-separated next to each other.

Comment: @ilkkachu That’s a nice idea, but arguments are not options. It’s a matter of taste in the end, one could easily call `-d/` obfuscated as well and advertise `-d "/"` or `-d '/'` instead, or frown upon run-together-options and always type `ls -a -l`. But if you feel this way, let me add an explanatory comment… I like to throw in unorthodox things like that in my answers just to show what’s possible. I *always* answer comments asking for explanations, normally extending my answer.

Answer (score 12):

You need to set your `IFS='/'` for `read` and then assign each first field into separate variable `first` and the rest of the fields into variable `rest` and just work on first field's value (Or you can `read -ar array` to a single array and use `"${array[0]}"` for the first field's value. ):

```
while IFS='/' read -r first rest;
do
    echo mkdir -- "$first" 
done < test.txt
```

###Or in single line for those who like it:

```
<test.txt xargs -d'\n' -n1 sh -c 'echo mkdir -- "$'{1%%/*}'"' _
```

###Or create all directories in one-go:

```
<test.txt xargs -d'\n' bash -c 'echo mkdir -- "$'{@%%/*}'"' _
```

The [ANSI-C Quoting `$'...'`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) is used to deal with directory names containing special characters.

Note that the `_` (can be any character or string) at the end will be argv[0] to the `bash -c '...'` and the `$@` will contains rest of the parameters starting from 1; without that in second command the first parameter to the `mkdir` will be lost.

In `${1%%/*}` using [shell (POSIX sh/bash/Korn/zsh) parameter substitution expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), removes longest possible match of a slash followed by anything till the end of the parameter passing into it which is a line that read by *xargs*;

P.s:

- Remove `echo` in front of the `mkdir` to create those directories.
- Replace `-d'\n'` with `-0` if your list is separated with NUL characters instead of a `\n`ewline (supposed there is/are embedded newline in your directory name).

Answer (score 6):

Contents of `test.txt`:

```
A 12"x4" dir/B b/C c
A1/B1/C1
A2/B2/C2
A3/B3/C3
```

Script to create `A[123]` folders:

```
file="test.txt"
while read -r line ; do
   mkdir "${line%%/*}"
done < "$file"
```

Output of `ls`:

```
A 12"x4" dir
A1
A2
A3
```

Comment: How do you deal with input like: `A 12"x4" dir/B b/C c`?

Comment: Ole Tange - That comment seems completely out of scope for the question.

Answer (score 6):

For simple case as shown in the question's input example, just use `cut`  and pass output to `mkdir` via `xargs`

```
cut -f1 -d '/' file.txt | xargs -L1 mkdir
```

For handling cases where directory name may contain spaces, we could add `-d '\n'` to the list of options:

```
$ cat input.txt 
A 1/B 1/C 1
A 2/B 2/C 2
A 3/B 2/C 2
$ cut -f1 -d '/' input.txt | xargs -d '\n' mkdir 
$ ls
A 1  A 2  A 3  input.txt
```

For more complex variations, such as `A 12"x4" dir/B b/C c` as suggested by @OleTange in the comments, one may turn to `awk` to create null-separated list instead of newline-separated list.

```
awk -F'/' '{printf  "%s\0",$1}' input.txt |  xargs -0 mkdir
```

---

@dessert in the comments wondered whether `printf` can be used instead of `cut` , and technically speaking it can be used, for instance via limiting the printed string to the width of 3 characters only:

```
xargs -d '\n' printf "%.3s\n"  < input.txt | xargs -L1 mkdir
```

Not the cleanest way, but it proves `printf`  can be used. Of course, this gets problematic if directory name becomes longer than 3 characters.

Comment: How do you deal with input like: `A 12"x4" dir/B b/C c`?

Comment: @OleTange See the edit.

Answer (score 2):

using Perl:

```
perl -ne 'mkdir for /^(\w+)/' list.txt
```

Or

```
perl -ne 'mkdir for /^([^\/]+)/' list.txt
```

if we want to accept spaces on dir-names

Comment: `perl -ne 'mkdir for /^([^\/]+)/' list.txt` to cover spaces in dir names. I finally need to learn Perl – thank you!

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel may be overkill for the task, but if you are going to do other stuff for each line, then it may be useful:

```
cat myfile.txt | parallel --colsep / mkdir {1}
parallel -a myfile.txt --colsep / mkdir {1}
```

It deals correctly with input like:

```
A 12"x4" dir/B b/C c
```